# Whats causing Drupal to freeze when creating/editing a mini-panel?

Tags: caching, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-panels

I'm quite new to drupal.

Drupal has been freezing for me when I try and create or sometimes edit a minipanel. Once I select the panel layout and start adding content it just remains in the lightbox 'grayed' state and wont let me click or do anything. It's almost like it's trying to load but I've left it for an hour and it's completely frozen.

I've tried on Firefox and IE10 and get same issue. Also upgraded my drupal from 7.23 to 7.24 today so a completely new core is running but still hangs like this.

I haven't fully explored everything yet in drupal so I don't know if other sections will do this. So far it's just the minipanels section.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It was because I was running jQuery 1.8. I went into configuration->development->jQuery update and switched to 1.7 = problem solved.